# How to show pie chart when we have a value only

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, report

I am passing all the count to report Dataset. 
now my dataset is 

**ID : 1 
Total : 5 
perso : 2 
Remaning :2 
Rejected : 1**

Have a only one row which contain above value

SO, my question is how to show pie chart with the help of this value only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Why would the number of values change the way you set up the chart?

Comment: have you tried creating a chart with these values?

Comment: Yes i tried, but "Chart expert" is not added a value of this field. It is added Count of this field

Comment: so that it shows 1,1,1,1 for all these three field.       But i want 5,2,2,1.  and pie chart should have to show like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating chart, you need to do following things

- pick pie char
- pick "advanced layout" and select "for all records"
- put sums of field you wanna display on pie char

For better understanding below is picture

[image]

Hope it helps